# ¿Cómo volver una lista una fila de números?

Tags: python

Hola estoy trabajando en Python y tengo un problema, para una lista con un único elemento como aparece en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
numbers = ['20090819']
```

¿Cómo puedo convertir esa fila de números en otra lista?

He probado con .split() pero no me funciona.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cómo intentaste usar split?

Comment: number_1 = numbers.split()

Comment: ¿Algo así `list(numbers[0])`?

Comment: Gracias justo en el clavo

Comment: Podrías explicarme ¿Por que le agregaste [0] a la variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes esto:

```
numbers = ['20090819']
```

que aunque sea un solo elemento, sigue siendo una lista, para separar cada dígito de este elemento, en primer lugar debemos "extraer" el elemento en sí:

```
print(numbers) # aunque sea de un solo elemento sigue siendo una lista
['20090819']  

print(numbers[0]) # Extraemos el primer elemento de la lista, una cadena
20090819
```

Con el índice `0` extraemos el primer valor de cualquier lista. Luego la forma más sencilla de dividir una cadena en caracteres, es convertir cualquier cadena en una lista:

```
print(list(numbers[0]))
['2', '0', '0', '9', '0', '8', '1', '9']
```

Si eventualmente quisieras una lista, pero de enteros, hay que convertir cada caracter en un valor numerico, por ejemplo:

```
print(list(int(e) for e in list(numbers[0])))
[2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a la respuesta de Patricio, sólo me gustaría agregar el uso de la función map.
Map aplica una función a un iterable.

```
numeros = ['2', '0', '0', '9', '0', '8', '1', '9']
numeros_int = list(map(int,numeros))
```

Lo que hace map es que aplica la función int() a cada elemento de la lista.
Supongamos que quieres duplicar el valor de cada elemento de la lista.

```
def duplicar(num):
    return num*2

numeros_int = [2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8, 1, 9]
numeros_doble = list(map(duplicar, numeros_int ))

[4, 0, 0, 18, 0, 16, 2, 18]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas